# How to create Status Bar icons for Android

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have created a **Xamarin Forms** app and have enabled push notifications. The notifications are appearing just fine, but the icon is always just a grey box on the **Android** version.

I need to create icons for the app that can be displayed in the status bar. I'm not a graphic designer, and just want to display a very simple icon. I read somewhere that if I specify just the **-xxhdpi** version that **Android** will automatically resize all icons for smaller screens, but this doesn't seem to be working.

What is an easy way to create the icons I need for **-hdpi, -xhdpi, -xxhdpi** resolutions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [AndroidAssetStudio](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/).

**Android Asset Studio** is a web-based set of tools for generating graphics and other assets for Android applications that helps developers create graphic assets with just a few clicks. Currently available asset generators include:

- Launcher icons - the visual representation of your app
- Action bar icons - are graphic buttons from top application bar and represent the most important actions
- Notification icons - is the icon that the system it’s display in the status bar when a new notification appears
- Generic icons - are small / contextual icons used in the body of your app
- Simple nine-patches - generate graphics elements for different screen densities
- App Theme - create simple and attractive custom action bar style